# How can I modify the format of the I2C HAL functions on CubeIDE?

Tags: debugging, embedded, stm32, i2c, stm32cubeide

I want to read the GSR1 and GSR2 registers of the XRA1201 using I2C. The STM32U5 family's HAL libraries have functions called HAL_I2C_Mem_Read, where you only need to pass the parameters. However, the XRA1201 requires retransmitting the device address after the register address. How can I resend the device address without sending a stop bit?

[XRA1201 I2C BLOCK DIAGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANrcH.png)

I tried to use Read_Mem, and Write_Mem on a private function, but didn´t work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to clarify your issue. Did you check what is on the bus actually if you call `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read()`? Its documentation should tell you something, too. I'd expect that this function already does resend the address, because it needs to _write_ the memory address and then to _read_ the requested data. Since these are separate I²C accesses, an address is inevitable. However, a "repeated start" is used instead of "stop" followed by "start" in between.